# How to integrate Kerberos into FastApi?

Tags: python, fastapi, kerberos

Is there an existing way of integrating Kerberos authentication into [FastApi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)?

I can see in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146591/custom-authentication-for-fastapi) details of creating a custom authentication method. The FastApi docs [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/) describe how to implement Basic Auth. Am I correct in thinking that I need to modify this to return a 401 with Www-Authenticate: Negotiate for no token and validate a supplied token in the Authorization header? Is there an example in Python where this is fine or is there a ready-made Kerberos library for use with FastApi already?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Kerberos via SPNEGO is implemented through the `Negotiate` mechanism in WWW-Authenticate. You could use the Python `spnego` or `gssapi` or `sspi` or `sspilib` modules to validate the Kerberos token (the first one being cross-platform, the other two being for Linux and Windows respectively). In most cases it's fairly simple:

- For python-pyspnego, create a `spnego.server()` to validate the token.
- For python-gssapi, create a `gssapi.SecurityContext(creds=..., usage="accept")`.
- python-pykerberos may also work, but it's much less pleasant to use.

The ticket will be validated against the system default keytab (or $KRB5_KTNAME); the `gssapi` module allows specifying custom server credentials via code, otherwise you need to specify the keytab via os.environ.

```py
mech, _, in_token = req.headers["Authorization"].partition(b" ")
if mech == b"Negotiate":
    # contexts are not reusable -- each HTTP request is a brand new auth
    context = gssapi.SecurityContext(usage="accept")
    in_token = base64.b64decode(in_token)
    # step() throws exception on auth failure
    out_token = context.step(in_token)
    out_token = base64.b64encode(out_token)
    out_hdr = b"WWW-Authenticate: " + mech + b" " + out_token
```

---

I don't have an example for FastApi specifically, so I'll pretend it's a generic ASGI application – here's a mostly-working ASGI port of the WSGI middleware that I was using in my various WSGI-based projects:

```py
# (c) 2021-2023 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
# Released under the MIT and/or CC BY-SA 4.0 licenses, whichever is suitable
import asyncio
import base64
import gssapi

class GSSAPIWrapper():
    def __init__(self, app, *,
                       service_name=None,
                       keytab_path=None,
                       credentials=None):
        if service_name and credentials:
            raise ValueError("'service_name' and 'credentials' are mutually exclusive")
        if keytab_path and credentials:
            raise ValueError("'keytab_path' and 'credentials' are mutually exclusive")

        if not credentials:
            if not isinstance(service_name, gssapi.Name):
                service_name = gssapi.Name(service_name or "HTTP@",
                                           gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)
            if keytab_path:
                credentials = gssapi.Credentials(name=service_name,
                                                 usage="accept",
                                                 store={"keytab": keytab_path})
            else:
                credentials = gssapi.Credentials(name=service_name,
                                                 usage="accept")

        self.app = app
        self.creds = credentials
        # If you wish, you can simplify the above to store just the
        # service_name instead of doing anything with Credentials;
        # then pass it as SecurityContext(name=self.service_name, ...)
        # for each request. This will just use $KRB5_KTNAME to find
        # the keytab.

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope["type"] != "http":
            return await self.app(scope, receive, send)

        in_hdr = dict(scope["headers"]).get(b"authorization", b"")
        if in_hdr.startswith(b"Negotiate "):
            ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(creds=self.creds, usage="accept")
            in_token = base64.b64decode(in_hdr[10:])
            out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
            #out_token = await asyncio.to_thread(ctx.step, in_token)
            if ctx.complete:
                scope.setdefault("extensions", {})
                scope["extensions"]["REMOTE_USER"] = str(ctx.initiator_name)
                async def custom_send(event):
                    if out_token and event["type"] == "http.response.start":
                        out_hdr = base64.b64encode(out_token)
                        event.setdefault("headers", [])
                        event["headers"].append((b"WWW-Authenticate",
                                                 b"Negotiate " + out_hdr))
                    await send(event)
                return await self.app(scope, receive, custom_send)

        # No input header, or the context didn't complete in 1 step
        await send({"type": "http.response.start",
                    "status": 401,
                    "headers": [(b"WWW-Authenticate", b"Negotiate")]})
        await send({"type": "http.response.body",
                    "body": b""})
```

In most cases you don't need the flexibility and can just specify the keytab path through `KRB5_KTNAME` in the environment, so you might want to port it to the `spnego` module for additional portability (as it works on both Windows using SSPI and Linux using keytabs):

```
# (c) 2021-2024 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
# Released under the MIT and/or CC BY-SA 4.0 licenses, whichever is suitable
import asyncio
import base64
import spnego

class GSSAPIWrapper():
    def __init__(self, app, *, hostname=None):
        self.app = app
        self.hostname = hostname

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope["type"] != "http":
            return await self.app(scope, receive, send)

        in_hdr = dict(scope["headers"]).get(b"authorization", b"")
        if in_hdr.startswith(b"Negotiate "):
            ctx = spnego.server(hostname=self.hostname,
                                service="HTTP",
                                protocol="negotiate")
            in_token = base64.b64decode(in_hdr[10:])
            out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
            #out_token = await asyncio.to_thread(ctx.step, in_token)
            if ctx.complete:
                scope.setdefault("extensions", {})
                scope["extensions"]["REMOTE_USER"] = str(ctx.client_principal)
                async def custom_send(event):
                    if out_token and event["type"] == "http.response.start":
                        out_hdr = base64.b64encode(out_token)
                        event.setdefault("headers", [])
                        event["headers"].append((b"WWW-Authenticate",
                                                 b"Negotiate " + out_hdr))
                    await send(event)
                return await self.app(scope, receive, custom_send)

        # No input header, or the context didn't complete in 1 step
        await send({"type": "http.response.start",
                    "status": 401,
                    "headers": [(b"WWW-Authenticate", b"Negotiate")]})
        await send({"type": "http.response.body",
                    "body": b""})
```

Comment: When you signed up for Stack Overflow, you agreed to publish your contributions under the Creative Commons BY-SA license (which version depends on when this was posted. The [timeline link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75917889/timeline) next to each post - the clock icon below the votes - provides this detail; in this case, currently, CC BY-SA 4.0)